# AngularJS Bootstrap alert dismiss-on-timeout attribute doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, timeout, alert, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use AngularJS Bootstrap alerts like explained [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with the "dismiss-on-timeout" attribute. It has no effect in this example, the alert just appears regularly and doesn't disappear.

```
<alert type="warning" dismiss-on-timeout="2000">Alert text</alert>
```

It does however work in the ng-repeat example from the site:

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" dismiss-on-timeout="2000">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

Is the problem the missing close attribute? If so, how do you write a close function for an alert that's not part of an array?

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ovNkuePOra371EUzMge?p=preview

Comment: Yes as I said, there is no problem when using the ng-repeat on an array of alerts. But I am looking for a single alert, and as you can see if you copy the first code bit it does not work there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well it works, it's just `dismissOnTimeout` directive invokes [`close` method](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/alert/alert.js#L30) of the alert directive controller. This controller in its turn uses outer scope `close` method. So you need to implement it with so that directive could call it:

```
<alert type="danger" close="closeAlert()" ng-if="show" 
       dismiss-on-timeout="2000">Something happened.</alert>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.show = true;

$scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.show = false;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I suspected it was about the close method, but wasn't sure how to implement it.

Comment: What is "close" method ?

Comment: @Imran https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/d6b9ee17e57b6f826c5d4725f39b813f7cff4c61/src/alert/alert.js#L27

Comment: It would be great, if any example for usage also available . Thanks!

Comment: I gave example in the answer. You just need to implement callback to be called by Angular.

Comment: @Imran Then it means that you are not doing it right. Post your code or create a demo so I could look, otherwise it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you do not need to use the variable (`$scope.show = false;`) to hide the alert(s). All you need to do is to make sure that the array that holds the alerts can only have one item at a time, unless you want multiple/previous alerts showing on the screen. Just delete the alert after showing it. See below:

**Markup**

```
<uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" dismiss-on-timeout="2000" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert()">{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>
```

**Controller**

```
//array to hold the alerts to be displayed on the page
$scope.alerts = [];

/**
 *This function is used to push alerts onto the alerts array.
 */
$scope.addAlert = function(type, message) {

    //add the new alert into the array of alerts to be displayed.
    $scope.alerts.push({type: type, msg: message});
};

/**
 *This function closes the alert
 */
$scope.closeAlert = function(index) {

    //remove the alert from the array to avoid showing previous alerts
    $scope.alerts.splice(0); 
};
```

So when you want to display an alert:

```
$scope.addAlert('success', 'My message');
```

Comment: I also applied same as your code but only dismiss timeout base alert did not hide. So, how can i manage ? Please suggest thanks

Answer (score 1):

I never could get it to work.  Here's a more straightforward approach:

**Markup**

```
<div uib-alert 
     data-closeable="true"   <!-- sets the 'x' on the right for closing -->
     close="closeAlert()"    <!-- what the 'x' and the timeout will call -->
     alert alert-{{ alert.level }}"   <!-- sets the color (e.g. 'success' or 'danger')  -->
     ng-show="alert.show">   <!-- only show me when this is truthy -->
     {{ alert.message }}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.closeAlert = function() {
    $scope.alert.show = false;
}

$scope.showAlertForFiveSeconds = function(){
    $scope.alert.message = 'Something went wrong!');
    $scope.alert.level = 'danger';  // red
    $timeout(closeAlert, 5000);  // close the alert in 5 seconds
}
```

Essentially all I'm doing is manually setting a deferred call to close the alert and walking away.

*Note that doing this also requires you to inject the Angular $timeout service into the controller up top.*

Answer (score 1):

My proposal would be to wrap it in a `alertFactory` that can be used from everywhere:

```
App.factory('alertFactory',['$rootScope', 
    function($rootScope) {
    var alertService = {};
    $rootScope.alerts = [];

    // will automatidally close
    // types are success, warning, info, danger
    alertService.addAuto = function(type, msg, delay) {
        var alert = {'type': type, 'msg': msg};
        $rootScope.alerts.push(alert);      
        if (!delay ) {
            delay = 2500; // default delay is 2500ms
        }  
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            var index = $rootScope.alerts.indexOf(alert);
            if (index > -1) {
                $rootScope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
                $rootScope.$apply(); // refresh GUI
            } 
        }, delay);
    }

    return alertService;
}])
```

Place this, e.g. in your `index.html

```
<script src="components/angular-ui-bootstrap-bower/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
...
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

Call like

```
App.controller('myCtrl', [ "alertFactory", function(alertFactory) {

    var optionalDelay = 2500;
    alertFactory.addAuto('success', 'my alert text', optionalDelay);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is correct, however it is outdated so here is the updated version.

**In View:** ( Updated in Angular UI Bootstrap )

```
<uib-alert type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert()" dismiss-on-timeout="2000" ng-if="show">
  {{alert.msg}}
</uib-alert>
```

**In Controller:**

```
$scope.show = true;

   $scope.closeAlert = function() {
     $scope.show = false;
   };

    $scope.alert = {type: 'danger', msg: 'Something gone wrong'};
```