# validation message hide in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using below code as a validation message. i am trying to hide my validation message if its success message. please check my code

```
    <div uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts"  ng-class="'alert-' + (alert.type || 'info')" dismiss-on-timeout="{{alert.type == success ? '5000' : ''}}"
    close="alerts.splice(index, 1)">
   {{alert.msg}}
```

alert. type can be 'success or error'. i need to hide this only if, 'alert.type= success'. i tried. but not working. how i add condition. thanks

Comment: Take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023558/angularjs-bootstrap-alert-dismiss-on-timeout-attribute-doesnt-work)

Comment: this is not ok with my problem. ' dismiss-on-timeout' should work only success messages, (alert.type==success)

Comment: Is success a variable in `alert.type == success ? '5000' : ''`?

Comment: alert.type variable can be 'success' or 'error'

Comment: i need to hide my div , only alert.type = success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the string `success` and `5000` as a number, also the else condition would be `none` instead of `''`. Combining all these, you will need:

```
dismiss-on-timeout="{{ alert.type == 'success' ? 5000 : 'none' }}"
```

[Plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/TgnoqXbIsWqwqBCE)